# Location of WSDL.exe

Tags: .net, web-services, sdk, wsdl

I recently heard of WSDL.Exe, but I am not sure where to find this program.
Does anyone know where I can find or download it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'll get it as part of a Visual Studio install (if you included the SDK), or in a standalone SDK install. It'll live somewhere like `C:\program files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin`

If you don't already have it, you can download the .NET SDKs from
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569263.aspx

Answer (score 37):

In case anyone using VS 2008 (.NET 3.5) is also looking for the wsdl.exe.  I found it here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\wsdl.exe

Comment: and for future versions C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\vx.xx\bin\wsdl.exe

Comment: Mine was here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools

Comment: Mine was here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools

Answer (score 25):

And on my Windows 7 machine it is here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools

Note that the file wsdl.exe is portable, in that you can copy it to another windows machine and it works.  I have not tried to see if the 4.5 exe will work on a machine that only have .NET 2.0, but this would be interesting to know.

Comment: Surprisingly it is portable. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 8):

If you have Windows 10 and VS2019, and the .NET Framework 4.8, below you can see the **Location of WSDL.exe**

Path in your pc **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools**

Answer (score 5):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\wsdl.exe

(via this question: [Where can I find WSDL.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953012/where-can-i-find-wsdl-exe))

Answer (score 5):

If you have Windows 10 and VS2015, below you can see the **Location of WSDL.exe**

Path in your pc **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7 Tools**

Answer (score 3):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools

Answer (score 3):

You can find what you want in windows by looking with the windows dir command, use the administrator account to make it easy:

c:>dir wsdl.exe /s

Answer (score 0):

It is included with .NET (not sure if only in the SDK).