# Add Service Reference doesn't generate proxy

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, proxy

I understand there are other similar questions, but I haven't been able to find a working response.

I create the default WCF service from the template [which comes with GetData() and GetDataUsingDataContract()].
It runs fine in the browser.

I have a separate web site to which I add this new WCF service:

I do 'Add Service Reference', enter my URL, the service comes up and I click 'OK' to add it.
Under 'App_WebReferences', I see the namespace of my added service: 'ServiceReference1', with 'References.svcmap' under it, and a couple .svcinfo/.wsdl/.xsd files under that.

No proxy files are created, but `<system.serviceModel>` element is added to my web.config, with what seems to be proper information.

However, with no proxy, I can't access/call any methods in my service (ie `ServiceReference1.WCFMethod1()`)

I can call svcutil, generate the proxy, add it to my App_Code, and everything works as it should.
My question is, why isn't my proxy being created with 'Add Service Reference'?
Everything is under target framework: .NET Framework 4.

**EDIT:**

Just created a Console App and added the service reference and it created the proxy.
So the issue is my web site is not creating the proxy...

Comment: Did you add a using (Imports for VB.NET) statement to the code-behind for the page trying to call the service? I.e., `using <namespace>.ServiceReference1;` or something similar?

Comment: If you are using a web site "project" (File->New Web Site), then it does not create proxies and does not build, until runtime.

Comment: John,  yes I am using that.  So, no other way than to use svcutil?

Answer (score 8):

I had this same problem and found that unchecking **Reuse types in all referenced assemblies** did solve the problem.  However, in my case, I needed it to reuse types from some of my referenced libraries.  I found [this post](http://www.naveenbhat.in/2013/07/mvc-4-wcf-add-service-reference.html), covering a very similar problem.  In that post, it references a [Microsoft knowledge-base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2750149) which describes a fix for the the following issue:

> Consider the following scenario:
>
> - You create an ASP.NET MVC4 Web API project in Visual Studio 2012.
> - You add a WCF service reference in the project.
>
> In this scenario, the Reference.cs file for the service reference is empty.
>
> **Cause**
>
> This issue occurs because the `DataContractSerializer` class has encountered a type (`Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken`) that it does not support. In this case, it throws an exception, and then stops generating the service reference.

I wasn't referencing that JSON library, but, based on that bug description, I surmised that one of my referenced libraries must have had a similar problem.  I figured that one of the libraries that I was referencing probably contained a type that was not supported by the `DataContractSerializer`, it was throwing the same kind of exception, and it was therefore failing in the same way.

Sure enough, I found out that, in my case, the culprit was one of my own libraries which happened to include a public proxy for the same WCF service.  I suspect it was that public proxy that was causing the trouble.  In any case, by selecting **Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies**, and then selecting all of the assemblies *except* that one, the service reference automatically generated the proxy classes correctly.

Answer (score 4):

When you are adding a ServiceReference :  References -> Add new service reference.
Clik on advanced button and uncheck "Reuse types in all referenced assemblies". 
This option sometimes causing errors.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the main issue.
The issue source is  when you are not able to find Add Web Reference in your visual studio. If the service is asmx, in my case it wasn't generating proxy class until I found these steps -> click on Sercice Reference -> Click on Advanced -> There you will see Add Web Reference... Provide your service URL hit OK issue resolved.
Hope this helps.