# How to reference XSD in XML for W3C Markup Validation Service?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I would like to create a XML that follows the XML schema http://www.oid-info.com/oid.xsd . This XSD should be somehow referenced in the XML file, so that a tool like the https://validator.w3.org/ can check it to find errors in the semantics of the data, e.g. when an email address is invalid.

First, I tried it this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<oid-database xmlns="http://www.oid-info.com/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.oid-info.com/oid.xsd">
<submitter>
....
</submitter>
<oid>
....
</oid>
</oid-database>
```

The [**W3C Markup Validation Service**](https://validator.w3.org/) says:

> No DOCTYPE found! Checking XML syntax only. The DOCTYPE Declaration
>   was not recognized or is missing. This probably means that the Formal
>   Public Identifier contains a spelling error, or that the Declaration
>   is not using correct syntax, or that your XML document is not using a
>   DOCTYPE Declaration. Validation of the document has been skipped, and
>   a simple check of the well-formedness of the XML syntax has been
>   performed instead.

Ok, so I tried to use DOCTYPE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE oid-database>
<oid-database xmlns="http://www.oid-info.com/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.oid-info.com/oid.xsd">
<submitter>
....
</submitter>
<oid>
....
</oid>
</oid-database>
```

Now the W3C Validator says:

> Line 2, Column 23: no internal or external document type declaration
>   subset; will parse without validation

I do know what a DTD is, and I have worked with DTDs in the past. I know that a DTD is missing here. But I want to check against a XSD, and not against a DTD.

What do I have to do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) will check well-formedness and will validate against a DTD; it doesn't validate against an XSD.  You'll have to use another on- or off-line validator.

Also, here is how your XML file should look to hint that it should be validated valid against the [OID XSD](http://www.oid-info.com/oid.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<oid-database xmlns="http://oid-info.com"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://oid-info.com 
                                  http://www.oid-info.com/oid.xsd">
  <submitter>
    ....
  </submitter>
  <oid>
    ....
  </oid>
</oid-database>
```

See also: [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)

Note that those XSDs appear to have their own issues, including:

> [Warning] xhtml-light.xsd:8:36: schema_reference.4: Failed to read
>   schema document 'xml.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2)
>   the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is
>   not .
>
> [Error] oid.xsd:91:46: InvalidRegex: Pattern value
>   '{?\s*(((([a-z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*\s*((\s*(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\s*))?|(0|[1-9][0-9]*))){2,}\s*)|((0|[1-9][0-9]*)(.(0|[1-9][0-9]*))*))\s*}?'
>   is not a valid regular expression.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. Which tool did you use to validate this XML ? The tool http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html does require that you enter the XSD manually. I would like that it reads it directly out of the XML plus downloads further referenced XSDs (like the xhtml-light.xsd) automatically.

Comment: I don't use an online validator, but [this one](https://devutilsonline.com/xml/validate) would seem to meet your requirements; I use an off-line, Xerces-J-based validator.