# FATAL ERROR: The schemaLocation attribute does not contain pairs of values

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an XSD with the following heading:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns="http://suri.hacienda.pr.gov.IITPRM2019.schema"
           targetNamespace="http://suri.hacienda.pr.gov.IITPRM2019.schema">
```

I am doing the programming to create a file with the information in XML.

This is the heading I wrote on the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns:PR482_2019 xmlns:ns="http://suri.hacienda.pr.gov.IITPRM2019.schema"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://suri.hacienda.pr.gov.IITPRM2019.schema">
```

But when I check if the XML is well formed, this is what I got:

> ETieInd2019.xml:2,194: FATAL ERROR: The schemaLocation attribute does not contain pairs of values.

How can I eliminate this error?

Answer (score 2):

As the error tells you, `xsi:schemaLocation` values must be ***pairs***, separated by whitespace.

```
xsi:schemaLocation="NAMESPACE_URI LOCATION"
                                 ^^^^^^^^^ missing in your declaration
```

To solve the problem, add **LOCATION** as a system identifier specifying the physical location of the XSD.

(Note that there can be multiple pairs if you have multiple namespaces for which to specify associated XSDs.)

**See also**

- [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)