# XSD problem - cannot find the declaration of root element

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I've got a problem validating my XML file against my XML Schema. Everything works perfectly except it shows that it cannot find the declaration of `countries` root element.

Here is part of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<countries xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="kraje.xsd">
    <!-- I don't paste everything that's inside the countries element 
         since it's not causing errors -->
</countries>
```

Here is part of my XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="countries" type="countriesType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="countriesType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="country"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XML

Since your XML is in a `https://www.w3schools.com` namespace, change

```
xsi:schemaLocation="kraje.xsd"
```

to

```
xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com kraje.xsd"
```

### XSD

Add a matching `targetNamespace`,

```
targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com"
```

to the `xs:schema` root element.

### See also

- [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)