# global declaration error in XML XSD validation

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am brand new to XML and XSD creation. I am in the very basic stages of trying to form validating schema. However, I have spent a lot of time going in circles on this. If someone could review and please give me a better understanding of what is happening with the code? It is saying there is no global declaration for the root reports.

The error code reads as

> Cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element 'xs:reports'., Line '1', Column '134'.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:reports xmlns:xs="https://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="user.xsd">

    user(
    userID SERIAL,
    username varchar(255),
    password varchar(255),
    firstname varchar(255),
    middlename varchar(255),
    lastname varchar(255),
    email varchar(255),
  dob date,
    gender varchar(10)
  profile_photo bytea,
  home_phone varchar(50),
    cell_phone varchar(50),
    created_date timestamp default current_timestamp
  );
</xs:reports>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="reports">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="user">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="userID" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="username" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="middlename" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="dob" type="xs:date"/>
              <xs:element name="gender" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="profile_photo" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="cell_phone" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="created_date" type="xs:dateTime"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remedy your immediate error of failing to associate the XML with an XSD, read [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)

Then, actually follow the XSD when writing your XML:

```
<reports>
  <user>
    <userID>123</userID>
    <username>John Smith</username>
    ...
  </user>
</reports>
```

There's also a question of why the XSD would have `user` being a child of `reports`, but you can get your existing XSD working as is with new XML as a first step.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!! All issues were resolved.