# How to reference local XSD from XML file?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I want to write a simple XML file with a custom xsd file located in the same local directory on my computer. I don't understand the necessary syntax at the beginning of the files (I have googled but XSD tutorials seem to focus on the element definitions rather than the `xsd:schema`).

My sys_params.xsd begins:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">

<xsd:element     name="shipOrder" type="order"/>
```

My sys_params.xml begins:

```
<shiporder orderid="889923"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com sys_params.xsd"

<orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
```

My XML reports this validation error on the xml:

> Error schema document 'sys_params.xsd' has different target namespace
>   from the one specified in instance document 'http://www.w3schools.com'

No doubt my code is quite wrong but I need some help to correct it please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com sys_params.xsd"
```

to

```
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="sys_params.xsd"
```

because your XML is not in a namespace.

**See also:**

- [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085) to understand how to reference an XSD from an XML file, depending on whether namespaces are being used or not.
- [How to reference a local XML Schema file correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19253402/290085) if you have trouble stating the specification of the local XSD file. [Note, however, that despite the title similarities, the other link I provide is actually what will help you most with your question.]