# <fo:external-graphic src=... > throws error

Tags: c#, xslt, apache-fop

I use fop 2.1 and I need to load an external graphic with an absolute path. I tried this:

```
    <fo:root xsl:use-attribute-sets="text-attributes">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
         ...

        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="master">
            <xsl:call-template name="pageHeader"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="pageFooter"/>

            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                ...
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>

   ...

<xsl:template name="pageHeader">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="region-before-first">
        <fo:block>
           <fo:external-graphic src="url({concat('file:/',$logo-image)})" height="15mm" content-height="15mm"/>  
        </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
</xsl:template>
```

$logo-image contains the absolute path like C:/users/.../application/logo.gif

I get the following error:

```
PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
SEVERE: Invalid property value encountered in src="url(file:/C:/users/.../application/logo.gif)"  .... Invalid URI specified
```

Any idea?

I tried also to put ' around like "url('file:/C:/users/.../application/logo.gif')" and else at divers place. No success... :-(

---

As in some other stylesheets I do have external graphic that functions I tried also take the header into the normal flow ( => not static ). Not really the way to do for a header, but a try... :

```
    <fo:root xsl:use-attribute-sets="text-attributes">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
         ...

        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="master">
            <!--<xsl:call-template name="pageHeader"/>-->
            <xsl:call-template name="pageFooter"/>

            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:call-template name="pageHeader"/>
                ...
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>

   ...

<xsl:template name="pageHeader">
    <fo:block-container position="absolute" top="10mm" left="10mm">
        <fo:block>
           <fo:external-graphic src="url({concat('file:/',$logo-image)})" height="15mm" content-height="15mm"/>  
        </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
</xsl:template>
```

**But:** Independantly if I put

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url({concat('file:/',$logo-image)})" height="15mm" content-height="15mm"/>
```

or

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url({concat('file:///',$logo-image)})" height="15mm" content-height="15mm"/>
```

I get same stupid error:

```
.... Invalid URI specified
```

Comment: if anything the file protocol is `file://` . In your example at least two `//`  are missing, see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme. Did you verify your fop processor implementation does support the file protocol?

Answer (score 1):

First, simplify matters by getting it to work as a static FO file, independent of XSLT.  You can double-back to the XSLT once you have a static target FO file working.

Realize that as [@rene commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44972748/foexternal-graphic-src-throws-error#comment76920526_44972748), you have to use full URI syntax, which may actually require yet another `/` for local access.  (Think `protocol://host/path` where protocol is 'file' and host is empty here, yielding three slashes in a row):

```
file:///c:/users
```

If you still have trouble with this, do a [***browser walk up the directory tree***](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19253402/290085) to make sure that the files and its ancestor directories all exist.

Finally, note that `...` isn't valid, in case that's a typo for `..` and not a meta-notation about elided path components.

Comment: The "..." was only to shorten the path in this post ;-) . It is a real path to my local directory and the file exists. I had already tried the "file:///c:/users" version - but no success. Always getting the same error :-(

Comment: Yet your self-answer indicates that what I suggested is what in fact worked.   Hmm...........

Answer (score 0):

Oups, I got!

It's a silly Windows slash / backslash thing...!

When getting the image path, I just had to convert the slashes:

```
string logoImg = BackslashToSlash(Path.GetFullPath(imageFile));
xsltArgumentList.Add("logo-image", logoImg);
...

    public static String BackslashToSlash(String inStr)
    {
        try
        {
            return inStr.Replace("\\", "/");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

In the stylesheet (xsl) you can even the one-slash version after "file:" (!):

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url({concat('file:/',$logo-image)})" />
```

Nevertheless I think it actually should be three-slash one:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url({concat('file:///',$logo-image)})"
```

Comment: So when you told us that ***logo-image contains the absolute path like C:/users/.../application/logo.gif***, that was not actually true?

Comment: It does contain the absolute path! It's like "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\applicationName\temp\logo.gif". One of the sucking things is that there was a mix of "\" and "/".  :-(

Comment: **But your question already specifically says that you used forward slash (`/`)**, so saying that the answer to your question is to convert backslash to forward slash  is incongruent.

Comment: Might look so - but when you don't know that *this* is the problem, you sometimes don't pay attention first.

Comment: You have asked 16 questions and [***accepted***](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) 0 to date.  That coupled with your posting of a self-answer that's incongruent with the facts of your question indicate that you really should read [ask] and many other of the [help] sections to make better and proper use of this site.  Thank you.