# Error: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, domparser

I think I made mistakes in XML file in DOCTYPE line. How can I solve my problem?

I using DOM library for parsing XML file. My XML file is named `firstTime.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE tests PUBLIC "firstTime.xsd">
    <tests xmlns="http://www.example.com/Report"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/Report firstTime.xsd">
        <test id="1">
            <coverage>65</coverage>
            <usedFramework>Junit4</usedFramework>
            <typeTest>Integration</typeTest>
        </test>
        <test id="2">
            <coverage>35</coverage>
            <usedFramework>Junit5</usedFramework>
            <typeTest>Module</typeTest>
        </test>
        <test id="3">
            <coverage>45</coverage>
            <usedFramework>Mockito</usedFramework>
            <typeTest>Integration</typeTest>
        </test>
    </tests>
```

My XSD file is named `firstTime.xsd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/Report"
           xmlns="http://www.example.com/Report"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="tests">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="test" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="coverage" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                            <xs:element name="usedFramework" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="typeTest" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

My code using Java:

```
try {
            File inputXml = new File(xmlPath);
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
            factory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
            factory.setValidating(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(inputXml);
        

        }catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException e){
            Logger.getLogger(XmlReader.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO,e.getMessage());
        }
```

Error occurs when I'm trying to run java app:

[image]

after i changed xml file by adding this lines

```
<!DOCTYPE tests SYSTEM "firstTime.xsd">
<!DOCTYPE tests PUBLIC "1" "firstTime.xsd">
```

i recieve this error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative solutions:

1. **Strongly recommended:** Delete the `DOCTYPE` line; it's rarely used with XSD.
2. Repair the `DOCTYPE` line to be SYSTEM, and reference a DTD:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE tests SYSTEM "firstTime.dtd">
   ```
3. Repair the `DOCTYPE` line to include both a publicId and a systemId, and reference a DTD:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE tests PUBLIC "your-public-id-here" "firstTime.dtd">
   ```

### See also

- [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)
- [XSD schemaLocation, targetNamespace, default XML namespace matching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62345530/290085)

Comment: Notice that your new error indicates that it's expecting a system identifier to a DTD, yet you're providing one to an XSD.   I've updated the answer to emphasize that you almost certainly do not want to use a DOCTYPE line with XSD.

Answer (score 2):

With `PUBLIC`, you need two strings:

```
ExternalID ::= 'SYSTEM' S SystemLiteral
             | 'PUBLIC' S PubidLiteral S SystemLiteral
```

See [the XML Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-ExternalID).