# Request image from WMS to local storage in Java

Tags: java, geotools, wms

I have been trying to retrieve image from WMS in Java using the Geotools and save the image locally. I have simply followed this link https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/1883964 by Ian Turton and from the official documentation https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/wms/wms.html

My code is

```
package wmsexplore;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.geotools.ows.ServiceException;
import org.geotools.ows.wms.WebMapServer;
import org.geotools.ows.wms.request.GetMapRequest;
import org.geotools.ows.wms.response.GetMapResponse;

public class WMSConnector {
  public static void main(String[] args) {


    URL url = null;
    try {
      url = new URL("http://maps.heigit.org/osm-wms/service?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.1.0");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      // will not happen
    }

    WebMapServer wms = null;
    try {
      wms = new WebMapServer(url);
      GetMapRequest request = wms.createGetMapRequest();
      request.addLayer("osm_auto:all", "");
      String format = "image/png";
      request.setFormat(format);
      request.setDimensions("1000", "1000"); // sets the dimensions of the image
                                           // to be returned from the server
      request.setTransparent(true);
      request.setSRS("EPSG:4326");
      request.setBBox("-71.13,42.32,-71.03,42.42");

      try {
        GetMapResponse response = (GetMapResponse) wms.issueRequest(request);
        if (response.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase(format)) {
          BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(response.getInputStream());
          File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
          ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
        } else {
          StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
          IOUtils.copy(response.getInputStream(), writer);
          String error = writer.toString();
          System.out.println(error);

        }
      } catch (ServiceException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // There was an error communicating with the server
      // For example, the server is down
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
      // The server returned a ServiceException (unusual in this case)
    }

  }
}
```

The error I have been getting is :

```
Feb 09, 2022 2:09:36 AM org.geotools.xml.XMLSAXHandler fatalError
SEVERE: FATAL White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
Feb 09, 2022 2:09:36 AM org.geotools.xml.XMLSAXHandler fatalError
SEVERE: col 50, line 1
Feb 09, 2022 2:09:36 AM org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService internalIssueRequest
SEVERE: Failed to execute request http://maps.heigit.org/osm-wms/service?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.0&SERVICE=WMS
Feb 09, 2022 2:09:36 AM org.geotools.xml.XMLSAXHandler fatalError
SEVERE: FATAL White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
Feb 09, 2022 2:09:36 AM org.geotools.xml.XMLSAXHandler fatalError
SEVERE: col 50, line 1
Feb 09, 2022 2:09:36 AM org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService internalIssueRequest
SEVERE: Failed to execute request http://maps.heigit.org/osm-wms/service?request=capabilities&service=WMS&wmtver=1.0.0
```

***What might have gone wrong here?*** Thanks for the help in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

From a quick check (and a google of the [error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67270505/error-white-spaces-are-required-between-publicid-and-systemid)) it looks like the XML document returned by that server is "invalid" as it has no `systemId` set.

I've not seen this error before so it might be due to a recent upgrade of the XML parser used by GeoTools or some other change, or a change in MapServer behaviour.  Technically, this isn't a GeoTools bug, but it would be nice to find a way to fix it so we can continue to use MapServer WMS.

Comment: Can you still run this code without issue? @IanTurton

Comment: I can run it against a local geoserver and a couple of remote servers

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is as the error message indicates.

In the code snippet below the
<< LF >> character sequence is to indicate a LF character. And any white space present is white space. Between the DTD URL string and the VendorSpecificCapabilities element there is no white space. Unless the LF character is considered white space; which I think is an edge case in an implementation. It is this that could be the cause of the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><<LF>>
<!DOCTYPE WMT_MS_Capabilities SYSTEM 
"http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.0/capabilities_1_1_0.dtd"<<LF>>
[<<LF>>
 <!ELEMENT VendorSpecificCapabilities EMPTY><<LF>>
 ]>  <!-- end of DOCTYPE declaration --><<LF>>
<WMT_MS_Capabilities version="1.1.0"><<LF>>
<Service><<LF>>
...
```

The line wrapping between the SYSTEM word and the DTD URL string is an artifact of stackoverflow