# XML format issue

Tags: xml, windows

Is there any way that language setting or format setting can cause XML to be formatted wrongly?
I have a particular case in which XML generated with the duplicate value of ID.
[image]

As you can see above, there are two entity types with the same ID (IDENT1).
This format gives me an error that The XML file does not meet the XML schema requirements.

It's important to say that it happens only in a particular pc, and I couldn't replicate it on other pc.  I suspect that it's maybe related to language setting formatting etc.

What can be the cause?

Comment: If the `Id` attribute is declared to be of type `ID` in the XML schema, the attribute values must be unique within the XML document. See http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_ID.html

Comment: I know that, but this behavior only happens in a specific pc. When I'm exporting the same in other pc, it's unique.

Comment: Ir seems extremely unlikely that this has anything to do with "language setting" or "format setting".

Comment: Do you have any idea what can be the cause? It seems that there is an issue with '0' every XML generated with dup IDENT1. (Only in a specific PC)

Comment: I have no idea. What do you mean by "When I'm exporting the same in other pc"? What software do you use? The question is only tagged with "xml".

Comment: I exporting an XML file from a web app. The issue I described above, happens on a specific laptop. I couldn't replicate it on my pc.

Comment: @IdoSegal, please edit your post and share both (1) your input XML and (2) XSD in a textual format.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way that language setting or format setting can cause XML
> to be formatted wrongly?

This isn't a format issue, it's a content issue.

The answer is yes. There are any number of things that can cause the content of an XML document to be incorrect. And there's no way we can guess the cause in your particular case. You just need to debug it: track back through the history to see what process corrupted the document, then find out what's wrong with that process.

Answer (score 1):

Precision in vocabulary helps:

- ***Format*** is rarely used in XML other than perhaps in the context of pretty printing – it's easier to read XML *formatted* with line breaks and indentation.

  You may or may not like how your XML is formatted, but your error has nothing to do with presentational whitespace.

  Less precisely, one might say that some data is *formatted* as XML.  This begins to get at the notion that something is wrong with substance of the data as represented in XML.  The next two more commonly used terms will help here.
- ***Well-formed*** is used to describe textual data that meets the rules required for being XML.  Your XML is *well-formed*.
- ***Valid*** is used to describe whether XML meets the additional rules specified by a schema (DTD, XSD, Relax NG, Schematron, etc).  To say that "the XML file does not meet the XML schema requirements" is to say that your XML is *invalid* (according to the rules of some schema).

If you're observing that validity varies per machine, then most likely it is the association between the XML and a schema file that is the difference.  (Possible but less likely: The tool used for validation or the application program issuing the error might vary, or included/imported/referenced XML or schema files might vary, etc.)  To resolve your problem, focus on how you're associating a schema with your XML file differently on one machine vs the other.

### See also

- [Well-formed vs Valid XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085)
- [How to reference a local XML Schema file correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19253402/290085)
- [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)
- The documentation for your validation tool or validating XML parser.