# "Cannot find the declaration of element" validating with XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm a complete beginner in XML, and I'm trying to learn XML Schema. I have these two files:

### note.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<note
 xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com/xml note.xsd">

   <to>Tove</to>
   <from>Jani</from>
   <heading>Reminder</heading>
   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>


</note>
```

### note.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"          targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns = "https://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="note">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name = "to" type ="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name = "from" type = "xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name = "heading" type = "xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name = "body" type = "xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>


</xs:schema>
```

In note.xml I get the error

> cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'note'.xml

on my root note element. I have seen other posts here but for more complex solutions but I am a complete beginner and don't understand a thing. I would appreciate it if you could guide me through this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com/xml note.xsd"
```

to

```
xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com note.xsd"
```

so that the namespace URL matches `xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"` in the XML document and `targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com"` in the XSD.

### See also

- [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)
- [How to reference a local XML Schema file correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19253402/290085)