# XML Validation: 'No matching global declaration available for the validation root'

Tags: xml, xsd, lxml, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I've seen several different posts about this issue, but none of the suggested solutions have solved my problem, which seems to indicate some fundamental misunderstanding on my behalf. I am under the impression there is a name-spacing issue between my XML and XSD, but I'm not sure how to solve it?

I'm getting the following error whilst validating my XML:

> Element `'{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}schema'`: No matching global declaration available for the validation root., line 1`

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOCUMENT_FILE
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="path\to\my.xsd">
    <DOCUMENT>
        <BRANCH_NUMBER>num</BRANCH_NUMBER>
    </DOCUMENT>
</DOCUMENT_FILE>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">
  <xsd:element name="DOCUMENT_FILE">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xsd:element name="DOCUMENT" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
              <xsd:element name="BRANCH_NUMBER" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML is valid against your XSD. (Your fundamental understanding is sound.) There's likely just a minor problem in how you're specifying the path to the XSD.

**XSD in same directory:**

Replace

```
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="path\to\my.xsd">
```

with

```
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="my.xsd">
```

**XSD in another relatively specified, local directory:**

```
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="path/to/my.xsd">
```

**XSD in another absolutely specified, local directory:**

```
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///path/to/my.xsd">
```

**XSD in a remote directory:**

```
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://example.com/path/to/my.xsd">
```

### See also

- [How to reference a local XML Schema file correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19253402/290085)
- [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)

---

**Update after chat:** We read the error message more closely and realized that it was about a failure to validate the XSD itself, not the XML.  The above tips on XSD path specification may be useful to future readers, so I'll leave this answer as-is anyway.

Bottom line: If you see a validation error regarding the `schema` element, check that you're actually calling the validation routine with the XML file specified corrected and not the XSD file in its place.