# Cannot find the declaration of 'p:Peminjaman'

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm trying to do simple xml. but it shows `cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'p:Peminjaman'` as an error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<p:Peminjaman xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="namespace tes.xsd" xmlns:p="namespace">
    <p:PinjamanDetail>
        <p:Buku>
            <p:Judul>Widget </p:Judul>
            <p:Jumlah>1</p:Jumlah>
            <p:Category>Programming</p:Category>
        </p:Buku>
    </p:PinjamanDetail>
    <p:CustomerDetail>
        <p:Nama>James</p:Nama>
        <p:Alamat>
            <p:Line1>15 Some Road</p:Line1>
            <p:Line2>SomeTown</p:Line2>
        </p:Alamat>
    </p:CustomerDetail>
</p:Peminjaman>
```

here is the code, please help since I really don't know what's wrong :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post your XSD, but if you're looking for guesses:

1. `tes.xsd` lacks `targetNamespace="namespace"` on the `xs:schema` element.
2. `Peminjaman` is not defined as a top-level element in `tes.xsd`.
3. `tes.xsd` is not well-formed or invalid.
4. `tes.xsd` cannot be found.

If you'd like less guessing and more definitive answering, post a minimum, complete viable example of your issue, including your XSD.

### See also

- [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)
- [How to reference a local XML Schema file correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19253402/290085)