# How to use WSDL / Soap?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl, asmx

i'm working on a project where i need to create an rss-fee from information i get by a web service. I have worked with FULLREST Apis but i don't know anything about how i do this with web-services.

From what i could understand by reading the documentation:
-There is a Server
-I send him xml-files which are containing my requests
-I get xml-files which are containing the responses

I guess i could work into how i make these xml-requests but i just don't know how and to whom i send my xml-files and there are'nt any explanations in the documentation.
The target-urls are .asmx(never heard of it before) but .asmx?WSDL is also allowed.

One sentence in the documentation is: "The target address to pass the xmlString to is different for each Web Service, see chapter XSD & WSDL.
HttpSoap and HttpPost are allowed."

I've read about Soap and i know Curl but i dont see the connection between my problem and soap / httppost.

Thats all i can give you.

Hope someone could explain me what this is and how i need to use it. A short example would be great.

Comment: I find SOAPUI [link](http://www.soapui.org/) invaluable for SOAP testing.  You just put in the WSDL address (the .asmx?WSDL  URL) and it will pull back all the information you need about the Web Service including all the methods and their parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this article and get an understanding.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337535/Understanding-the-Basics-of-Web-Service-in-ASP-NET

And if you have the WSDL file, follow the solution in the link below to create the web service reference,

[How to generate service reference with only physical wsdl file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710281/how-to-generate-service-reference-with-only-physical-wsdl-file/12731330#12731330)