# Can i use a Service Reference with ICodeCompiler in order to create a unit test?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a unit test that will compile an interface that I created from a service reference. The problem is that when I use `ICodeCompiler` to compile the interface, it throws error:

> **Error**: The type or namespace name 'RoleAssignment' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The `RoleAssignment` class comes from the service reference. Is there a way I can add to the `ICodeCompiler` as a parameter the service reference?
thank you

this is the method I have

```
 CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider();
        ICodeCompiler compiler = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();
        CompilerParameters parametersForInterface = new CompilerParameters();           
        parametersForInterface.GenerateInMemory = true;
        parametersForInterface.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        parametersForInterface.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.Services.Client.dll");
        parametersForInterface.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.ComponentModel.dll");
        parametersForInterface.OutputAssembly = "inMemoryAssembly.dll";
        StringBuilder interfaceSC = new StringBuilder();
        CompilerResults results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromFile(parametersForInterface, path+ @"a\IA.cs");
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        // If there were errors, raise an exception...
        foreach (CompilerError ce in results.Errors)
        {
            if (ce.IsWarning) continue;
            sw.WriteLine("{0}({1},{2}: error {3}: {4}", ce.FileName, ce.Line, ce.Column, ce.ErrorNumber, ce.ErrorText);
        }
        // If there were errors, raise an exception...
        string errorText = sw.ToString();
```

errorText is the error mentioned above.
I have a service reference added to my unit test, and when I add the IA.cs file to my project I get no errors. 
IA.cs is an interface that I generated from the service reference reference.cs.
I don't know if there is a way to add the service reference to the ICodeCompiler
Thank you

Comment: You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates what you're trying to do. From that, people can tell you what you're getting wrong.

Comment: So you're trying to compile the service reference code via code which already references `RoleAssignment`, which is in the not-yet-compiled code? Perhaps try explaining your problem, not how you're trying to solve it... Why do you need to compile code with ICodeCompiler?

Comment: I just added more information about the problem I am having. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A service reference is simply a generated `.cs` file. Add the service reference to a project in Visual Studio, then either reference that project's output in `ReferencedAssemblies` or locate the `.cs` file and pass its path to `CompileAssemblyFromFile`.

If you wish, you could also generate the `.cs` file manually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12710348/2101267