# Visual Studio Adding Service Reference without internet connection?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do i add a Service Reference without internet connection or copy it from one project to another?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you asking this question without an internet connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get WSDL of service. You can add service reference from a file using WSDL provided.

Please see:
[How to generate service reference with only physical wsdl file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710281/how-to-generate-service-reference-with-only-physical-wsdl-file)