# call webservice(asmx) Using POST method

Tags: c#, web-services, http

hi i want to call my web application's web service from desktop application in c# i have tried this but it gives error internal server error 500.my URL of web service is too long so i need to pass it with POST method.
what is not right in my code ? any suggestion please.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL OF Webservice");
            //WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            //response.Close();

            using (var wb = new WebClient())
            {

                var data = new NameValueCollection();
                data["authU"] = "value";
                data["authP"] = "value";
                data["cmp"] = "value";
                data["sales_id"] = "value";
                data["Login"] = "value";
                data["total_amount"] = "value";
                data["total_discount"] = "value";
                data["net_amount"] = "value";
                data["change"] = "value";
                data["tax"] = "value";
                data["ip"] = "value";
                data["Tran_Type"] = "value";
                data["mac_id"] = "value";
                data["ref_id"] = "value";
                data["venue_id"] = "value";
                data["store_name"] = "value";
                data["actual_total_amount"] = "value";
                data["temp_sale_id"] = "value";
                data["is_return"] = "value";
                data["created_date"] = "2018-06-14 14:26:09";
                data["modify_date"] = "2018-06-14 14:26:09";
                data["mode"] = "value";
                data["value"] = "value";
                data["machine_id"] = "value";
                data["location_id"] = "value";
                data["input_amount"] = "value";
                data["sale_type"] = "value";
                data["is_table"] = "value";
                data["Payment_Date"] = "2018-06-14 14:26:09";
                data["Payment_Amount"] = "value";
                data["Table_name"] = "value";
                data["is_close"] = "value";
                data["values"] = "value";

                var response = wb.UploadValues("http://localhost:53653/POS_WebService.asmx/Sales_Master_Full", "POST", data);
                string responseInString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting data to web services isn't the standard way to interact with them. You point to a copy of the WSDL, in this case, at:

```
http://localhost:53653/POS_WebService.asmx?WSDL
```

and let VS create a proxy wrapper for calling the functions.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12710348/656243 for how to add the reference. From there, assuming you added the reference as WebService1, you can just call the function as member of the webservice:

```
WebService1 svc = new Webservice1;
var data = svc.Sales_Master_Full();
```

as if it were a normal C# function.

Comment: so i need to give .asmx file reference in this reference or particular webservice  (sales_master_full) reference?

Comment: Did you follow that link in the middle of my answer with explicit steps on how to add the web service? In that process, you'll be prompted for the URL, which in your case is: http://localhost:53653/POS_WebService.asmx?WSDL

Comment: i have added reference still get same error 'The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.'

Comment: no get error only The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. this error

Comment: I would contact the developer of the webservice, to try to understand why their code is erroring out. It's either because you are passing arguments into the function that the service doesn't understand, or because their code has a bug.

Comment: is this necessary to add this reference http://localhost:53653/POS_WebService.asmx?WSDL  'WSDL' after service string. sorry for silly question but i don't have knowledge of  it

Comment: Yes; that `?WSDL` is necessary to request the WSDL for the service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174002/discussion-between-nimisha-prajapati-and-lynn-crumbling).

Comment: is it create any problem if web service in vb.net and my desktop application in C#?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the HTTP Content type header as follows:

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    wb.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    var data = new NameValueCollection();
    // ...
    var response = wb.UploadValues("http://localhost:53653/POS_WebService.asmx/Sales_Master_Full", "POST", data);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: i have tried it also but get error only 'The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.'

Comment: Check the error on your server to see what is going wrong.