# How to generate proxy class with wsdl.exe when my file imports other wsdl and xsd files?

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2012, wsdl, wsdl.exe

I have a wsdl file and I'm trying to generate a proxy class with VS 2012 wsdl.exe tool, but when I try I get the following error message:

C:\VISUAL_STUDIO_PATH>wsdl.exe "C:\PATH_TO_FILE\AmHub_service_1_0.wsdl"

Error: Cannot find definition for http://www.csapi.org/wsdl/parlayx/v1_0/interface:CloudMovil.  Service Description with namespace http://www.csapi.org/wsdl/parlayx/v1_0/interface is missing.
Parameter name: name

My **AmHub_service_1_0.wsdl** file imports a **AmHub_interface_1_0.wsdl**, which at the same time imports a **parlayx_common_faults_2_0.wsdl** from another namespace, and two other xsd files from different namespaces, called **AmHub_types_1_0.xsd** and **parlayx_common_types_2_1.xsd**.

The problem I think the tool is having, is that inside both **AmHub_interface_1_0.wsdl** and **parlayx_common_faults_2_0.wsdl** an **xsd:import to parlayx_common_types_2_1.xsd** is being made. I've read that the wsdl tool can't generate the proxy when this kind of situation is present.

How can I generate my proxy class for this kind of situation? Do I stick with the wsdl tool or are there other tools for Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: see the answer by Jarek Mazur on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304281/create-web-service-proxy-in-visual-studio-from-a-wsdl-file

Answer (score 0):

I went through this and the best way is using visual studio. Download wsdl file into a folder and put all schemas (xsd files) in it. Then Add Service Reference.

[image]

Add route to wsdl file.

[image]

Press OK and you are ready to go.