# Where can I find WSDL.exe?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sdk, visual-studio-sdk, wsdl.exe

I have Visual Studio 2010 Ulitmate (with MSDN Premium), but I can't seem to find this file.

I have tried installing the Visual Studio SDK but I can't seem to find the file.

I have looked in:

- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\SDK\v3.5

But I can't seem to find it.

(In case you are wondering, I need it to perform [these steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa179614%28SQL.80%29.aspx#).)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

it should be under C:\Program Files (x86)\MicrosoftSdks\Windows\v7.0a\Bin . You should be able to use wsdl from visual studio command prompt and typing path in visual studio command prompt will give you the locations of all tools that you might need. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you!  Full path was: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin  (By the way, it was not run-able from the command prompt, but your path got me there.  Thanks again!

Comment: Did you try the path command in visual studio command prompt? I am just asking out of curiousity. Ah sorry I saw your comment below. A statement in the obvious but may be you need to set path for your visual studio command prompt to point to wsdl.exe location to allow running it from visual studio command prompt

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4876410/1219280) shows an easier approach.

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio 2010 comes with its own command prompt with a lot of functionality ready to use. You can invoke the wsdl command from there

Comment: Alas, it does not work.  (I open the VS 2010 Command Prompt and type in wsdl.exe and it says "'wsdl.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.")

Comment: just use the word wsdl, run it as administrator

Comment: Do you have other visual studio versions installed? VS2008?

Answer (score 1):

Can't run wdsl.exe directly from the command prompt because it's not in the DOS search path.  You will need to explicitly indicate the full path to the wdsl.exe

I haven't tried the code below but you should be able to run it as a prebuild action on your project.

MsBuild script

```
<Target Name="UpdateWebReference"> 
    <Message Text="Updating Web Reference..."/> 
    <Exec Command="wsdl.exe /o &quote;$(OutDir)&quote; /n &quote;$(WebServiceNamespace)&quote; &quote$(PathToWebServiceURL)&quote;"/> 
</Target>
```