# .net 2.0 wsdl.exe directory must be set in global preferences

Tags: .net, web-services, soapui

I have a SOAP UI project and I am trying to convert its WSDL to .NET so that I can use it in my visual studio application.

When I tried using the option, Generate Code - > .NET 2.0 artifacts I get the above error.

can someone tell me how to resolve it ?

Comment: What error? The question doesn't make sense unless a) you entered `wsdl.exe` by hand somewhere and b) that application's path isn't in the PATH environment variable. This has nothing to do with .NET or Visual Studio

Comment: wsdl.exe means ? sorry. I'm a newbie to SOAP UI

Comment: And c) wsdl.exe isn't used since 2008. It was used to generate ASMX classes from wsdl documents. These have been replaced by WCF and the `svcutil.exe` tool. Why are you using `wsdl.exe`? What `Generate Code` command do you refer to?

Comment: `wsdl.exe` means wrong choice or wrong configuration. What are you trying to do? BTW the earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2, not 2.0

Comment: Anyway, SOAP UI's documentation [explains what you have to do](https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/soap-code-generation.html). There's a duplicate question as well, which points to the same instructions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Location of WSDL.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100705/location-of-wsdl-exe)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know it's a bit late, but this is the first area link that pops up when you google this issue.

[*Using SoapUI 5.4.0*]
**1.** File -> Preferences
**2.** Select "Tools" in the side menu
**3.** Locate: ".NET 2.0 wsdl.exe" option in the right pane, and enter the path to wsdl.exe.

Comment: It works for me. I run soapui as administrator. The path for wsdl.exe for me is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools

Comment: I'm using a windows 10 computer and the path to wsdl.exe was slightly different.  I made my way to Microsoft SDKs and searched for wsdl.exe in file explorer.  When setting the directory in SOAPUI it asks you to do exactly that, set the directory.  I only mention it because it is slightly tricky in that interface because it will not show you if the wsdl.exe file is in that directory or not, which is why I used File Explorer to first locate it.  Everything worked great, thank you guys for the help!

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\wsdl.exe"